# Why Webix datatable cell values disappear after editing if template :function is used?

Tags: templates, datatable, webix

In one of my Webix datatable cells (editable), I am using a template:function to fetch and display the value. Now if I edit any of those cells, that edited value is not showing up instead the old value is showing.

If I again click on that cell, then I am able to see the newly typed value.
Why it is happening and how can I show the newly edited value in that cell.
It is happen only for cells under columns which is using template function.

In the below snippet please check that under parent column 'Place' , if I edit cells under 'climate' column the value is not showing up once mouse control is taken off. Same problem not happening for the cells under 'type' column.

Snippet: https://webix.com/snippet/8a63b3c7

What is the way to get rid of this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not using the template in right way, if you have to provide the constant value, there is no need to create the template. A template is used when we have to customize the data. Please follow the below link and please let me know in case you still face any issue, in template function first argument, provides the row data, please evaluate the field data from the row.

https://webix.com/snippet/310f5888

Comment: Your snippet is working. But in the case of a complex example, if I have two editable columns under Place, if I click on a cell to edit its value, its existing value disappears. Therfore, I am not able to edit its existing value. Either I have to remember the 
existing value or I need to put a entirely new value. Please see  Snippet : https://webix.com/snippet/a118ea86